# Saving a cropped image in R

Tags: r, raster

I am using `jpeg` package to read an image into R. This creates an object of class `nativeRaster`. I take a portion of this image using `[` operator. The resulting object is a matrix of integers. Attempting to save this object returns the error `image must be a matrix or array of raw or real numbers`. What should I do to be able to save this new image?

Below is a snippet to reproduce the error

```
imageFile = 'address of the jpg file'
outputFile = 'new file to write into' 

image = jpeg::readJPEG(imageFile, native=TRUE)
output =  image[1:10,1:10]
writeJPEG(image = output, target = outputFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was unable to find a solution, I am working around this by using solely imagemagick to crop the image.

```
system(paste('identify',
             imageFile), intern = TRUE) %>%
    regmatches(.,regexpr("(?<=[ ])[0-9]*?x[0-9]*?(?=[ ])",.,perl=T)) %>%
    strsplit('x') %>% .[[1]] %>% as.double
```

will return the dimensions of the image and

```
system(paste0('convert "',imageFile,
              '" -crop ',
              sizeX,
              'x',
              sizeY,
              '+',
              beginningX,
              '+',
              beginningY,
              ' "',
              outputFile,'"'))
```

will crop the image and save it to `outputFile`

Here `sizeX` and `sizeY` are desired dimensions of the cropped image and `beginningX` and `beginningY` designate the top left corner of the crop site on the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function writeJPEG takes image of type nativeRaster. I am not entirely sure about this but converting class of output to nativeRaster works for me.

```
class(output) <- "nativeRaster"
writeJPEG(image = output, target = outputFile)
```

Comment: You'll notice that the output pixel arrangement is not right. Pixels end up being shifted